# Line number debug information in my compiler

Tags: compiler-construction

I am trying to implement my own compiler.

As a result of compiler, I should receive assembler listing for NASM or FASM, that I will compile with that external assembler. But unfortunately, I did not find any way how to instruct NASM or FASM to generate line info in DWARF or STABS or in some other "source map" file where I will be able to read HighLevelSourceCodeLine_number->OffsetLengthInMachineCode".
Currently the only solution I see - create assembler by hand that will be able to do this, but it is not easy and short task.

May be someone has other ideas?

Comment: Does `%line` not work for you? http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.10.1 (You need to generate debugging info, I guess, using the `-g` command line flag: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.13)

Comment: Hm... It is definitely an answer. I have looked through NASM manual several times, but for some reason did not find this... Thank you.

Comment: Ok, made it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [NASM's `%line` directive](http://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.10.1). (To generate debugging info, you need to use the [-g command line flag](http://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.13).)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I looked for.